# In Google Bigquery, how to denormalize tables when the data is from different 3rd party source?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have data about contacts in Salesforce. I also have data about the contacts in Intercom/Zendesk. I want to create a denormalized table where the data in Salesforce and Intercom is both merged into a single table so I can query about the contact. Imagine, I dumped the Salesforce data into a Bigquery table. The problem is that the we might not dump Intercom/Zendesk until later. So we may only add Salesforce data into a Bigquery table now. And later we may add Intercom data. My question is how to merge these (existing data in Salesforce BQ table and new data from Intercom)? Assume that the Email is the primary key in both 3rd party sources and we can join them.

Do we need to take the Salesforce data out of the BQ table and run it through some tool to merge both tables and create a new table in BQ? 
What will happen if we keep getting new data in both Salesforce and Intercom?

Answer (score 1):

Your case seems to be a good use case for **Views**.

A **view** is basically a virtual table that points to a query. You can define a **view** based on a query (lets call it query_1) and then you will be able to see that **view** as a table. However every time you run a query (lets call it query_2) using that **view** as source, internally `BigQuery` will execute **query_1** and then execute your **query_2** against the results of query_1.

In your case, you could create a query that use `join` to merge your tables and save this query as a view. You can create a view by clicking on **Save view** in the `BigQuery` console just like in the image below and then fill some required fields before saving.

[image]

In BigQuery there are also **Materialized Views**, that implements some cache technologies in order to make the view more similar to a table.

Some benefits of materialized views are:

> - Reduction in the execution time and cost for queries with aggregate functions. The largest benefit is gained when a query's computation
>     cost is high and the resulting data set is small.
> - Automatic and transparent BigQuery optimization because the optimizer uses a materialized view, if available, to improve the query
>     execution plan. This optimization does not require any changes to the
>     queries.
> - The same resilience and high availability as BigQuery tables.

To create a materialized view  you have to run the below command:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  project-id.my_dataset.my_mv_table
AS <my-query>
```

Finally, I would like to paste here the reference links for both [views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro) and [materialized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro) in `BigQuery`. I suggest that you take a look at it and decide which one fits in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about querying Google Cloud Storage https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage.

You can take the extracts and place them into Google Cloud Storage under buckets i.e. Salesforce bucket and Zendesk bucket.

Once the files are available, you can create external tables on those bucket(1 table for each bucket) so that you would be able to query them independently.

Once you can query them , you can perform joins like normal tables.

You can replace the files in buckets when new data comes.